# Getting bash command output into an array in a shell script

Tags: bash

I have the following small script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

packages_installed=($(apt-cache -q pkgnames | tr - _ | tr . _))

echo $packages_installed

if [ ${#packages_installed[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "+unable_to_find_list_of_installed_packaged"
    logger -p user.error -t find_installed_packages "$(hostname -f) was unable to determine list of installed packages using apt-cache"
else
    for pkg in "${packages_installed[@]}"
    do
        echo "+installed_package_$pkg"
    done
fi
```

Running this however prints:

```
root@olympus:~# sh test.sh
test.sh: 3: test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

This seems to indicate I've made a mistake on the line where I generate the installed package list. However I'm pretty sure that's how you get a command output into an array?

Feels like I'm missing something dumb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Feels like I'm missing something dumb.

Indeed.

```
root@olympus:~# sh test.sh
test.sh: 3: test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

You are using `sh` to execute the script that is causing the error.  Your script seems fine and the array assignment shouldn't pose any problems.

Execute it using `bash` instead.

Comment: *sigh* I obviously feel like an idiot right about now. Thanks mate. Apologies for what must be the stupidest post here...

Comment: @Khushil Never underestimate the stupidity of others :) If you makes you feel better, `bash` still accepts some bash-isms even when invoked as `sh`, so it's not always obvious what will work and what won't.